# How to prove this assertion?

Tags: real-analysis

If $a<b$, then there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $a \leq b - 1/n$.

I was thinking I could use the Archimedean Property, but I don't know how since I need to get a non-strict inequality $\leq$.

I'd appreciate any hints or ideas. Thank you.

Comment: If you can show there is an $n$ such that $a\lt b-1/n$, then you have shown there is an $n$ such that $a\le b-\frac{1}{n}$. So the "$=$" part of $\le$ is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really equivalent to showing that if $\epsilon > 0$, then there is an integer $n$ for which

$$0 < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$$

(Try setting $\epsilon = b - a$). On the other hand, this is equivalent to showing that there is an integer $n$ for which

$$n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} > 0$$

The Archimedean property may be useful here. Note that if you find $n = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, you can always conclude that $n + 1 > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. This removes the issue about $\le$ versus $<$.

Comment: So, why is the statement $a \leq b - 1/n$ and not $a < b - 1/n$? I know $<$ implies $\leq$, but I think there should be a reason why they said $\leq$.

Comment: @Twink The statement that I proved ($a < b - 1/n$) implies the weaker statement $a \le b - 1/n$.